# Android: XML scale animation does not animate a button when inflating a dialog fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, animation, scale

I am developing a dialog fragment that scales from 0 to 1 on entry. I am getting the scale animation, but a button in my fragment is animated as a black view and the actual button color and text can be seen only when the animation is finished. How do I animate the button without having a black view for the button during the transition? Thanks in advance.

My code for scale entry animation:

```
<scale xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:duration="200"
android:fromXScale="0"
android:fromYScale="0"
android:interpolator="@android:interpolator/accelerate_decelerate"
android:pivotX="50%"
android:pivotY="50%"
android:toXScale="1"
android:toYScale="1" />
```

Fragment code:

```
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getActivity(), R.style.PopUpDialogTheme);

    View inflatedView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_view_ad_details, null);

    Button viewButton = (Button) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.view_btn);
    viewButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), OtherActivity.class);
            intent.putExtras(getArguments());
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    ImageView closeBtn = (ImageView) inflatedView.findViewById(R.id.close_btn);
    closeBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            dismiss();
        }
    });

    builder.setView(inflatedView);

    AppCompatDialog dialog = builder.create();
    DisplayMetrics displaymetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getActivity().getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displaymetrics);
    WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
    Window window = dialog.getWindow();
    lp.copyFrom(window.getAttributes());

    lp.width = displaymetrics.widthPixels;
    lp.height = displaymetrics.heightPixels;
    window.setAttributes(lp);
    dialog.getWindow().getAttributes().windowAnimations = R.style.PopUpAnimation;
    return dialog;
}
```

Pop-up animation theme:

```
<style name="PopUpAnimation" parent="AppTheme.Translucent">
    <item name="android:windowEnterAnimation">@anim/open_pop_up</item>
    <item name="android:windowExitAnimation">@anim/close_pop_up</item>
    <item name="android:colorBackgroundCacheHint">@null</item>
</style>
```

Fragment invocation:

```
DetailsFragment dialogFragment = new DetailsFragment(); dialogFragment.show(fragmentManager, dialogFragment.getTag());
```

Comment: Post your question with fragment code where your are using this animation.

Comment: @AjithPandian I have added the code